# Can I disable the transaction timeout in delphi?

Tags: database, delphi, transactions, timeout

I am currently working on a revision comparer, in order to check if every significant change was made in every branch of my project. The problem is, that I am uploading a huge dataset and get a timeout after a while. Probably because my transaction is shot down from my database to be on the safe side. I am assuming that the entire transaction or request will take longer than two hours.

```
procedure TRCForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Database := TDatabase.Create(Self);
   // Disbale transaction timeout here
end;
```

**Q.:** Is there a possibility to extend the maximum transaction duration or to disable it completely?

**Q.:** Another consideration was that the transaction might be storing too much data, which is why it ends at a certain point. Is that possible, and if so, can it be checked and also circumvented?

**Note:** I am using a ADOConnection.

I really appreciate any suggestions or ideas, sheers!

---

## Solution

Simply set the CommandTimeout to zero in order to disable any kind of timeout.

```
procedure TRCForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Database := TDatabase.Create(Self);
   Database.DBConnection.CommandTimeout := 0;
end;
```

See the [docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.CommandTimeout) here for more informations.

> Use CommandTimeout to specify the amount of time that expires before an attempt to execute a command is considered unsuccessful.

Comment: Please include the exact error message in your question. Also please indicate the database type.

Comment: I added the connection type. I have to say I forgot the exact error message, because it was 2 days ago at work. I will add it if my program throughs it again, it is currently running.

Comment: @MΛIK Is that huge upload will be executed once or it going to be some regular process? Because if its regular - it's not good idea to have DB operation running for hours, even on non-operational hours. In such long operation risk to get fail is big and you have to repeat it again. Why not split that big data load in smaller pieces?

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev It's only one time, after that is will executed daily with only very small datasets. We just have to form the basis for several branches of many years, which leads to extremely large amounts of data being created. Your suggestion to divide the data and upload it individually is our stopgap solution.

Comment: Look for the CommandTimeout property and set it to something bigger than 7200 (2 hours in seconds)!

Comment: @DelphiCoder Could I set it to 0? For infinite seconds?

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.CommandTimeout

Comment: No info about 0 in the docs

Comment: @DelphiCoder I am currently running it at 0 for around 1:30h and it is still running, so seems like it works!